# How to get element calling onload in AngularJS ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to get the element triggering an 'onload' event of an ng-include ? Something like $event in ng-click which I can use to get the element calling the onload function.

Answer (score -2):

ng-include takes an optional `onload` parameter, so you can fire any event or method you'd like

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

at the time of invocation, `this` likely refers to the element, although that depends on other factors.

Comment: Yep. I know. I'm asking how to pass the current element loading the template in the calling function. Thanks.

Comment: edited.. have you tried logging `this` when `onload` is invoked?

Comment: Not working. Placed onload="x(this)". Is this what you mentioned?

Comment: `onload="console.log(this)"`